# Find X contiguous segments in a range of integers

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I've been struggling with the following problem: how do I find all possible sub-ranges in a range of integers where each segment is at least length 1, and I specify the total number of segments? A couple examples:

```
segments=2, range=(0,5)
> [0,1],[2,5]
> [0,2],[3,5]
> [0,3],[4,5]

segments=3, range=(0,8)
> [0,1],[2,3],[4,8]
> [0,1],[2,4],[5,8]
> [0,1],[2,5],[6,8]
> [0,1],[2,6],[7,8]
> [0,2],[3,4],[5,8]
> [0,2],[3,5],[6,8]
> [0,2],[3,6],[7,8]
> [0,3],[4,5],[6,8]
> [0,3],[4,6],[7,8]
> [0,4],[5,6],[7,8]
```

This feels like a recursion problem because I need to iterate over a varible number of for-loops, but I don't see how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick piece of pseudo-code off the top of my head.

Given maximum value **m** and number of non-empty segments **n**, do so:

> Call Helper(Empty List [passed by reference], Empty List [copied before passing or passed by copy], 0, m, n)

The helper function takes as input:

1. a reference to the output list of lists,
2. a list of segments to append more segments to
3. the lower bound or starting value
4. the upper bound or stopping value
5. the number of segments

   ```
   function Helper(L, S, l, u, n):
     If n = 1 then append to L the list S.append(l, u)
     Else:
       For each t from l+1 up to u-n *inclusive*:
         Make a copy of S into S'
         Append to S' the pair (s, t)
         Call Helper(L, S', t+1, u, n-1)
   ```

As you can see, the only "trick" was perhaps just figuring that out you should use a helper function with more arguments to aid the recursion. Of course, different solutions may be possible.

A note here. It should be possible to change the implementation above slightly (e.g., using return values as opposed to passing L by reference) that one can memoize the result of each call for a given triple (l, u, n). Such a DP approach seems to me like it may make the program be significantly faster on large input. I assume this sort of problem has much sharing to be exploited using a DP approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1. Splitting a range into $k$ segments is the same as selecting the $k-1$ break-points between segments.

Hint 2. As you proceed through the list of elements, the next element is either part of the current segment or part of the next one.

Comment: Hint 1 is slightly wrong (should be $k - 1$ break-points) and Hint 2 is slightly vague (imo). Also it might be better to mention that the two hints correspond to two different ways of solving the problem ...

Comment: @WhatsUp Wow, I made the very archetype of off-by-one errors! :-) Thanks for spotting it. I take your point about the second one being a bit vague but I'm trying not to just give the whole answer -- maybe I went too far the other way. In my mind, the two hints were aimed at the same method but I don't think it's a problem if they move people in different ways.